# What's an approach to ML problem with multiple data sets?

Tags: machine-learning

What's your approach to solving a machine learning problem with multiple data sets with different parameters, columns and lengths/widths? Only one of them has a dependent variable. Rest of the files contain supporting data.

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is too generic and irrelevant to some extent as well. The concern around columns length and width is not justified when building a ML model. Given the fact that only one of the datasets has a dependent variable, there will be a need to merge the datasets based on keys that are common across datasets. Typically, the process followed before doing modelling is :

step 0: Identify the dependent variable and decide whether to do regression or classification (assuming you are predicting variable value)

Clean up the provided data by handling duplicates, spelling mistakes

Scan through the categorical variables to handle any discrepancies.

Merge the datasets and create a single dataset that has all the independent variables and the dependent variable for which prediction has to be done.

Do exploratory data analysis in order to understand the dependent variable's behavior with other independent variables.

Create model and refine the model based on VIF (Variance Inflation factor) and p-value.

Iterate and keep reducing the variables till you get a model which has all the 
significant variables, stable R^2 value. Finalize the model.

Apply the trained model on the test dataset and see the predicted value against the variable in test dataset.

Following these steps at high level will help you to build models.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful.